# Slax9.3 Abiword not opening

Tags: linux

Hi I installed `Abiword` with `apt` on `Slax 9.3`.

It created a shortcut but I can not run the Program.

I got the following **error message**:

```
root@slax:~# abiword
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to open swrast (search paths /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri:${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
gbm: failed to open any driver (search paths /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri:${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
gbm: Last dlopen error: /usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
failed to load driver: i965
gbm: failed to open any driver (search paths /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri:${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
gbm: Last dlopen error: /usr/lib/dri/kms_swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
failed to load driver: kms_swrast
gbm: failed to open any driver (search paths /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri:${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri)
gbm: Last dlopen error: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
failed to load swrast driver

(abiword:10714): GLib-ERROR **: /build/glib2.0-YYXhFA/glib2.0-2.50.3/./glib/gmem.c:100: failed to allocate 4263644068 bytes
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Comment: This looks like you have mulitple libEGL's on your system, and the incorrect one for abiword is first on your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Please perform this: `sudo find / -name libEGL*` and `sudo find / -name libGLESv2*`, report your findings.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution here.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/slax-users/rGMzROFsD80

There was a missing Library. Running this installed it:

```
apt install libgl1-mesa-dri
```

Now the Program opens fine.

Comment: What is the relationship between userid "Creative" and "Creative24"?

Comment: Same Person.I just realize i have two accounts. Now I have to figure out how to delete the one that I seldom use.

Comment: just flag your post here for a moderator's attention. And request those 2 accounts to be merged (indicate which one you want to keep). Pretty sure that'll do it. Good luck!

Comment: Actually, @Creative, please use the appropriate option in [the Contact Us page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/contact) to have the accounts merged.